Do Universal Links work when the link is wrapped by another link?
I work for an email marketing company where we send emails through SendGrid. The links go to ebay.com. SendGrid will wrap the links for click tracking purposes, so instead of the link appearing as https://www.ebay.com, it will be something like https://u99798501.ctc.sendgrid.net/... which will then redirect to eBay.
We've noticed that when clicking on these SendGrid-tracked links that redirect to eBay, the links do not open in the eBay app, even though we have the eBay app installed. They will instead open up in Safari. Clicking on the https://www.ebay.com links without the wrapping will open in the links in the eBay app.
This makes me think that the URL being wrapped by another URL is preventing Universal Links (links opening in the app) from working. However, we're pretty sure this did work at one point. Does anyone know the status of Universal Links with wrapped URLs? Did it change recently?
The iOS version that we tested with is 17.5.1. We are opening links from the iOS Gmail app.
Thank you!

Did you try with other mail clients, specifically iOS Mail?

URL schemes do not seem to have this problem.
